# Can't get the initial values of an HTML CSS Element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to manipulate a div element. Although I have defined certain property values, I can't seem to get the initial values.

Here's the problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9TdR/)

I'm at the end of my rope... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `document.styleSheets`, find your stylesheet, then loop through the cssRules(IE rules) list to match a selector to `"#viewbase"` and then you can access your style properties like you would have with inline styles, since the style info in there is also a CSSStyleDeclaration ( so you can use element.style.left and so on).

Sidenode: `getComputedStyle` doesn't work on most versions of IE. IE has `currentStyle` properties for each element, but it's not the same thing. Maybe a combination of both will also work.

**UPDATE**

Managed to get the initial positions, if that's what you need, you can reassign these values if i remember well.

```
function trigger(e) {

item = this;

if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    x1 = e.pageX;
    y1 = e.pageY;
}
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    x1 = e.clientX;
    y1 = e.clientY;
}

document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = x1;
document.getElementById("wye").innerHTML= y1;
// the stylesheet you defined, in a standalone context, it might 
// have another index, (i.e. 0 if it's the only one)
list = document.styleSheets[2].cssRules;

for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    //match #viewbase
    if(list[i].selectorText.toLowerCase() == "#"+item.id)
    { item = list[i];
      break;
     }

document.getElementById("xval").innerHTML = item.style.left;
document.getElementById("yval").innerHTML = item.style.top;

document.getElementById("parseX").innerHTML = parseInt(item.style.left, 10);
document.getElementById("parseY").innerHTML = parseInt(item.style.top, 10);

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = 'clicked!';

document.onmouseup = release;
}
```

**The other version would be to use the following**

```
var styleDef = window.getComputedStyle(item) || item.currentStyle;  
document.getElementById("xval").innerHTML = styleDef.left;
document.getElementById("yval").innerHTML = styleDef.top;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your style is not defined within the html but comes from css. In that case you need to use getComputedStyle to retrieve the styling information. Do something like

> document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(item,null)

rather than item.style.

Comment: What exactly does this return? How would I get specific property values from this?

Comment: It returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object, with the final used values of all the CSS properties of the element. Just replace item.style with this. For example, instead of item.style.left, use document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(item,null).left. See http://jsfiddle.net/ckWVB/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `item.offsetLeft` and `item.offsetTop`.  This will include margins and padding, but you should be able to easily compensate for this fact.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/Y9TdR/7/) is an updated JSFiddle.

```
document.getElementById("xval").innerHTML = item.offsetLeft;
document.getElementById("yval").innerHTML = item.offsetTop;
```

Again, in this case, these calls return `10, 10` respectively, instead of `0, 0`, which you are looking for.  That said, is this enough to move you past your issue?

Comment: If you do it this way, I have to know the margin value for the element and the parent objects border value...